# KeyBindings WPF not firing on load

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `UserControl` inside a `ContentControl`. I want the user control to be closed when I press the `Escape`key. So I used a `KeyBinding` like this:

```
 <UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource CloseCommand}" Executed="Close" />
 </UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

and

```
 <UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{StaticResource CloseCommand}" />
 </UserControl.InputBindings>
```

When the `Escape` key is pressed, this code is supposed to fire the `CloseCommand`. But the first time the UserControl is loaded it doesn't fire. If I navigate and change the `ContentControl` content with another UserControl, then it works.

Any idea on what's wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your control hasn't the focus when you press the escape key.
You should set the `Focusable` property of your `UserControl` to `True` and then call the `Focus()` method in the load event of your `UserControl`.